jqgrid date formatter from and to formats
I have the date coming in as 30-Oct-24 and I need it displayed as 30-Oct-2024 and also need to be able to sort by date
I have this code but it's not working and showing gibberish strings instead
 formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'd-MMM-yy', newformat: 'dd-MMM-yyyy' }, sorttype: 'date'

Is there a list of date formats for JqGrid that I can find somewhere? This should work but does not.

jqGrid follow the php date formatting. This is described into the documentation
In your case you can try with:
... srcformat : 'd-M-y', newformat : 'd-M-Y' ,...

